# In python, how to order a dict with unicode content?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-unicode, ordereddictionary

I've the following dict:

```
<type 'dict'>
{u'010-010': u'010-010_comp_v000', u'012-010': u'012-010_comp_v002', u'007-010': u'007-010_comp_v000', u'006-010': u'006-010_comp_v009', u'005-010': u'005-010_comp_v002'}
```

I want to order it by keys. But using Collections and OrderedDict, I can't get it working.

```
OrderedDict([(u'010-010', u'010-010_comp_v000'), (u'012-010', u'012-010_comp_v002'), (u'007-010', u'007-010_comp_v000'), (u'006-010', u'006-010_comp_v009'), (u'005-010', u'005-010_comp_v002')])
```

I assume it is linked to unicode? Is there a solution to correct this without having to rewrite the dict? It's an output of another soft so I can't change the type easily.

The desired output is: `'005-010'... '006-010'... '007-010'...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OrderDict`s retain insertion order - they don't sort the items for you. You'll need to sort them yourself:

```
d = {u'010-010': u'010-010_comp_v000', u'012-010': u'012-010_comp_v002', u'007-010': u'007-010_comp_v000', u'006-010': u'006-010_comp_v009', u'005-010': u'005-010_comp_v002'}
o = OrderedDict((k, v) for k, v in sorted(d.items()))
print(o)
```

Comment: @ScottHunter: The point is to retain insertion order. (The `u` prefixes say this is almost certainly a Python version where `dict` doesn't do that.)

Comment: The OP said "I want to order it by keys", so, maybe. We'll see if this is what they are looking for...

Comment: It's exactly what I was searching. Thanks!